# tapestry with jquery ajax upload component does not work in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, tapestry, multi-upload

Tapestry with jQuery j:ajaxUpload component does not upload files in IE.

Steps to reproduce

1. Go to link http://tapestry5-jquery.com/components/docsajaxupload
2. Click on the "Example" tab.
3. Click upload and select a jpg or gif or png file
4. The column "size" shows 0 in IE, but in Firefox/Chrome/Opera it shows the file size.

I think the size is 0 because the file is not being submitted to the server.

Can you suggest a fix for this problem.

I have to use this component because it allows multiple file upload.

I am using IE 9 on Windows 7 if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected and normal.  The browser does not provide the ability to determine file size client side in IE 9 or older.

Comment: As a workaround, you could report the correct size after reading all bytes from ```UploadedFile.getStream()```.